# Is it possible to put data in particular column of datagridview

Tags: datagridview, c#-3.0

Is there any way to show data from access table to some particular columns. For eg.
Table have following data
BCode   TCode1   Slot1  TCode2  Slot2   TCode3  Slot
Batch1    T1     10:00    T2    12:00
Batch2    T1     08:00    T2    09:00     T3    11:30
Batch3    T1     08:00    T2    10:00     T3    11:00

And my datagridview have following columns
BatchCode   08:00   08:30   09:00   09:30   10:00   10:30   11:00   11:30   12:00   12:30 and so on upto 20:00
I wan to show T1 under 16:00 T2 under 18:00 and t3 under 20:00
Means output should be some thing like this

BatchCode   08:00   08:30   09:00   09:30   10:00   10:30   11:00   11:30   12:00   12:30
B1                                            T1                              T2
B2            T1              T2                                      T3
B3            T1                              T2              T3

I tried many ways but not reaching to the output.

```
            aCommand1 = new OleDbCommand("select * from weekly where bday like 'Sun'", main_connection);
        aAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(aCommand1);
        ds1 = new DataSet();
        aAdapter1.Fill(ds1, "app_info");
        int recCount = ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 11;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Batch";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "08:00";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "08:30";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "09:00";
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "09:30";
        dataGridView1.Columns[5].Name ="10:00";
        dataGridView1.Columns[6].Name ="10:30";
        dataGridView1.Columns[7].Name ="11:00";
        dataGridView1.Columns[8].Name ="11:30";
        dataGridView1.Columns[9].Name ="12:00";
        dataGridView1.Columns[10].Name ="12:30";
        for (int k = 0; k < recCount; k++)
        {
            int p_count = Convert.ToInt32(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[k][2].ToString());
            int col_count = 5;               // Column number of starting time slot
            string[] str = new string[p_count];
            int i = 0;
            for (int x = 1; x <= p_count; x++)
            {
                col_count += 2;   

                for (int m = 1; m < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; m++)
                {
                    if (dataGridView1.Columns[m].Name == ds1.Tables[0].Rows[k][col_count].ToString())
                    {
                        str[i] = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[k][col_count].ToString();
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[k][0].ToString(), str[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

After a long wait for 3 hrs when I didn't got any answer or reply from here I asked this to a [cbsecsnip.in](http://cbsecsnip.in) and this code its working

```
for (int k = 0; k < recCount; k++)
        {
            int p_count = Convert.ToInt32(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[k][2].ToString());
            int col_count = 5;
            int teat = 4;
            string[] str = new string[p_count];
            int i = 0;
            string batchname = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[k][0].ToString();
            string[] teacher=new string[dataGridView1.ColumnCount];
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(batchname);
            for (int x = 1; x <= p_count; x++)
            {
                for (int m = 1; m < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; m++)
                {
                    string colname = dataGridView1.Columns[m].Name;
                    string tablecoltime = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[k][col_count].ToString();
                    if (colname == tablecoltime)
                    {
                        teacher[m] = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[k][teat].ToString();
                        dataGridView1.Rows[k].Cells[m].Value = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[k][teat].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        teacher[m] = "";
                    }
                }
                teat += 2; col_count += 2;
            }
        }
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
    }
```